# Variables declared with our and BEGIN block interactions

Tags: perl, scoping, lexical-scope

Why would an uninitialized variable behave/interact differently than an initialized variable in this situation:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

our($foo) = 0;
BEGIN {
        $foo = 2;
}

our($bar);
BEGIN {
        $bar = 3;
}

print "FOO: <$foo>\n";
print "BAR: <$bar>\n";
```

results in:

```
$ perl test.pl
FOO: <0>
BAR: <3>
```

Perl version:

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 22, subversion 0 (v5.22.0) built for x86_64-linux
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, it's not an initializer; it's a plain old assignment. It happens when the code is executed, not when the variable is created.

Secondly, `BEGIN` blocks are evaluated as soon as the block is compiled.

As such, what you wrote is basically equivalent to the following:

```
# Compile phase
use strict;
use warnings;    
our $foo;
$foo = 2;
our $bar;
$bar = 3;

# Runtime phase
($foo) = 0;
($bar);
print "FOO: <$foo>\n";
print "BAR: <$bar>\n";
```

---

More precisely,

1. Compile phase

   1. Compile `use strict;`.
   2. Execute `require strict;`.
   3. Execute `import strict;`.
   4. Compile `use warnings;`.
   5. Execute `require warnings;`.
   6. Execute `import warnings;`.
   7. Compile `our($foo) = 0;`. (Only creates `$foo`.)
   8. Compile `BEGIN` block:

      1. Compile `$foo = 2;`.
   9. Execute `BEGIN` block:

      1. **Execute `$foo = 2;`**.
   10. Compile `our($bar);`. (Only creates `$bar`.)
   11. Compile `BEGIN` block:

       1. Compile `$bar = 3;`.
   12. Execute `BEGIN` block:

       1. **Execute `$bar = 3;`**.
   13. Compile `print "FOO: <$foo>\n";`.
   14. Compile `print "BAR: <$bar>\n";`.
2. Runtime phase

   1. **Execute `($foo) = 0;`.**
   2. Execute `($bar);`.
   3. Execute `print "FOO: <$foo>\n";`
   4. Execute `print "BAR: <$bar>\n";`

As you can see,

- You assign `2` to `$foo` in 1.9.1, then you assign `0` to `$foo` in 2.1.
- You assign `3` to `$bar` in 1.12.1.

Comment: The distinction between initialization and simple assignment is key to helping me comprehend this, instead of just knowing it -- thank you.

Comment: It wouldn't make sense for `our` to have an initializer, seeing as `our $foo` creates a lexically-scoped alias to the package variable of the same name (just like `\my $foo = \$PACKAGE::foo;` does). That said, it's just an assignment for `my` too. (Why are you using `our` in the first place???)

Comment: I needed a packaged-scoped variable.

Comment: Extremely unlikely. Almost guaranteed to be a bug (very poor design), or use of `our` when `my` would work equally well.